# Is it considered on topic to ask about the dev's or the community, rather than specifically about Monero?

Tags: discussion

For example, I'd like to know the security/crypto/tech publications to which the dev's subscribe.  For that matter, those in the community (dev's or not) who are technically savvy and are getting daily/weekly/monthly updates about Linux and/or internet security and/or bleeding edge crypto news, etc... these individuals end up "speaking a different language," since they are privy to information that others are not.

A.  I want to know what publications I'm missing out on, for personal benefit/knowledge.

B.  I think the community would be better off if more people are "on the same page," as a result of being aware of the same relevant news and developments.

In fact, if this type of information is "out there," it would give tech savvy newcomers more context, so they could just hop in and get to work contributing to the project, rather than asking tons of questions and not always following through.

I understand that this could be considered off-topic and/or not really technical enough for the SE, so that's why I'm posting in the meta section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd like to know the security/crypto/tech publications to which the dev's subscribe.

That information would interest many but is better asked on [Slack](https://monero.slack.com/), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/monero) or the [Monero Forum](https://forum.getmonero.org/)

> I understand that this could be considered off-topic

I agree with this